# Как узнать, что тест на PhantomJS python работает

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Вот есть код. В логах все ок. Как узнать, что действительно работает?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon" + Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: А почему вы используете PhatomJS, а не Chrome или Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете вместо PhantomJS использовать Chrome или Firefox, чтобы посмотреть как ваш тест выполняется. После проверки, можете указать опции запуска --headless для того чтобы тест быстрее работал и не отображалось окно.

К тому же поддержка браузера PhantomJS Selenium прекратилась, об этом говорят предупреждения в тестах

```
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
```

Поэтому лучше используете Chrome или Firefox (первый по наблюдениям быстрее)

Также я производил сравнение показателей разных браузеров [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856143/selenium-webdriver-headless-%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B), и разные параметры запуска для браузера Chrome [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878715/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC/878756#878756)